# how to group all arguments as position argument for `xargs`

Tags: shell, command-line, xargs

I have a script which takes in only one positional parameter which is a list of values, and I'm trying to get the parameter from stdin with `xargs`.

However by default, `xargs` passes all the lists to my script as positional parameters, e.g. when doing:

`echo 1 2 3 | xargs myScript`, it will essentially be `myScript 1 2 3`, and what I'm looking for is `myScript "1 2 3"`. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the delimiter.

```
$ echo 1 2 3 | xargs -d '\n' printf '%s\n'
1 2 3
```

Not all xargs implementations have `-d` though.

And not sure if there is an actual use case for this but you can also resort to spawning another shell instance if you have to. Like

```
$ echo -e '1 2\n3' | xargs sh -c 'printf '\''%s\n'\'' "$*"' sh
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input can be altered, you can do this. But not sure if this is what you wanted.

```
echo \"1 2 3\"|xargs ./myScript
```

Here is the example.

```
$ cat myScript 
#!/bin/bash

echo $1; shift
echo $1; shift
echo $1;

$ echo \"1 2 3\"|xargs ./myScript
1 2 3


$ echo 1 2 3|xargs ./myScript
1
2
3
```